# Can't send GET request to Django via Postman

Tags: python, django, postman

I perform request http://167.71.57.114/api/users/list-exercises
And receive error

> User matching query does not exist.

**How can I fix the error?**

Found out that reason of the error is that request didn't have any data

But you can see that I am sendig the "user_id"

[image]

**My code**

```
class WorkoutUserProgramListViewAPI(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = WorkoutUserProgramListSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        response = {}
        user = request.data.get("user_id") # user is None
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user) # Error User matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: GET requests don't have a body, use Params!

Comment: Addition to @KlausD.'s comment: You could either use request params or provide the user_id as part of the API endpoint. Considering the URL, using params would look like `api/users/list-exercises?user_id=<user_id>`. If you make the user_id part of the API endpoint it would look like `api/users/list-exercises/<user_id>`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Klaus D said in the comments, you would rather put a user-id as a parameter. If you're sending user_id=29, I would add that as a parameter, which should change the URL to be something like

`http://167.71.57.114/api/users/list-exercises?user_id=29`

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when the `objects.get` method does not find any result.
If you use filter and verify that the result is not None you avoid that error in the case that the id passed by parameter does not belong to any user.

```py
class WorkoutUserProgramListViewAPI(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = WorkoutUserProgramListSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        response = {}
        user_id = request.data.get("user_id")
        user = User.objects.filter(pk=user_id).first()
        if user is not None:
            # code
        else:
            # code
```

Listen what [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) tells you, too.